# Index referencing with relative values

Tags: excel, indexing, worksheet-function

I'd like to reference a cell in a named range depending on a value outside of this named range

What I would like to see is ideally:

```
INDEX(named_range;;COLUMN()-RC1)
```

However, INDEX does not allow for the RC1 whilst it recognizes Column().

One way would be to make RC1 part of the named range (by copying the data into first column of range etc), but as the named range is somewhere completely different to the cell containing the formula, "I don't want to...".

Any other options to achieve it?

Thanks

*Addition:
Maybe the purpose helps. The aim is to find the number of installed units (named_range) that need to be replaced in the future depending on the lifetime which is in RC1.*

Comment: Is RC1 a cell reference?  If so, it works for me in Excel 2010.

Comment: Is the named range a single row?

Comment: @Doug: I get a reference error.
It is supposed to get the value from a cell (e.g. RC1) and subtract it from the current column index (e.g. 42-5).
Could you post a screenshot of the way you entered it? Thanks

Comment: I entered it assuming that the range was a single row, an assumption questioned by @barryhoudini.  I don't have much time now, but perhaps try, INDEX(named_range;ROW();COLUMN()-RC1)?

Comment: If 42-5 gives a #REF! error that probably means that you have less than 37 columns in your named range

Comment: Oh man, that hurts...because of Column() I somehow ignored that the counting for columns in INDEX does not start where the sheet starts...(despite remembering that for rows...)

The part should be Column()-x-RC1, where x = number of column where named range starts - 1 
If you post this in you clear words as an answer, you get the solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, you need to take into account the start column of the named range to get the correct column, possibly use

`=INDEX(named_range;;COLUMN()-RC1-MIN(COLUMN(named_range))+1)`

Answer (score 0):

INDEX has two version, you're thinking solely of the INDEX/MATCH (2D) version, but it also has an INDEX/MATCH/MATCH version, too.

**INDEX(My3DRange, MATCH("Y", MyYValues, 1), MATCH("X", MyXValues, 1))**

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not see how this solves my problem. The cell I pick shall be depending on the column the formula is in. The match functions reference static values I have to define first.

Comment: can you post a small picture like I did showing your sample data and your manually mocked up desired results?  That might make the issue clearer. Apologies.

Comment: It is alright, I made a mistake, see comments from me above. Solved.

Comment: I don't see an accepted answer, is this issue closed?  Any of these answers get you close to your answer?